# If point $(m,n)$ is selected from set A at random, what is the probability that $n > m+2 $?

Tags: probability

Let we have a circle with radius  2 and the center lies on the origin.  If point $(m,n)$ is selected from set A at random, what is the probability that $n > m+2 $ ?

In this case i have got a following  condition, 
$$y> x+2$$
Above the points, the condition will be satisfied.

But how to get the amount of the probability ?

The answer has been attached but i haven't got the marked  line 
[image]

Comment: $\color{#c00}{\text{NOT CLEAR!}}$ What is $A$?

Comment: Is $A$ the disk $x^2+y^2\le 4$? Do $m$, $n$ range over the integers or over the reals? Draw a picture and things should become clear.

Comment: It is quite clear , the set A contains all the coordinates that  satisfies the condition mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Point may be selected "at random" by infinitely many possible ways, assuming that the probability of a point being chosen from a set is proportional to that set's area:

1) Calculate the area of the set $\left\{ {\left( {x,y} \right):{x^2} + {y^2} < 4,y > x + 2} \right\}$ as follows:

Distance between the line $ - x + y - 2 = 0$ and the center of the disk $\left( {0,0} \right)$ is $d = \frac{2}{{\sqrt {{1^2} + {1^2}} }} = \sqrt 2 $, so the required area is equal to $\int_{\sqrt 2 }^2 {\left( {\int_{ - \sqrt {4 - {y^2}} }^{\sqrt {4 - {y^2}} } {dx} } \right)dy}  = \pi  - 2$

2) Divide that area with the area of the whole disk, which is $4\pi $. This is the probability you're looking for, in this case $\frac{{\pi  - 2}}{{4\pi }}$.

Answer (score 0):

Both the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and the line $y = x + 2$ intercept the $x$ and $y$ axes at $-2$ and $2$ respectively. So the area bounded by these equations is easy to calculate without integrating.

Area of one quarter of the circle is: $2^2\pi/4 = \pi$.

Area of the triangle formed by the two axes and line $y = x + 2$ is: $2$.

Subtract to get the bounded area we want: $\pi - 2$.

Area of the whole circle is: $2^2\pi = 4\pi$.

So the required probability is: $\dfrac{\pi - 2}{4\pi}$.